# Como muestro por consola un mensaje al obtener una opción con el value indicado?

Tags: jquery

Quiero que al seleccionar una opción con el value igual al indicado, muestre un mensaje por consola según le corresponda, pero no se porqué no me funciona, y ya he probado muchas formas, pero nada.

Código **HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>
            Prueba
        </title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <filter class="col-3">
               <select aria-label="Default select example" class="form-select">
                      <option selected="" value="0">
                            Filtrar por ...
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            Género
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            Año
                      </option>
              </select>
         </filter>
        <script src="jquery/prueba.js">
        </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

Código **JQuery**:

```
if ($(".form-select option").val("1")
        .is(':selected')) { 
            console.log("Se ha seleccionado la opción 1");
         }
         else if($(".form-select option").val("2")
         .is(':selected')){
            console.log("Se ha seleccionado la opción 2");
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He editado sólo jquery para lo que necesitas

```js
//Se ejecuta cuando se cambia una opción
$(".form-select").change(function(){
  //console.log("Valor: "+$(this).val());
  //console.log("HTML: "+$.trim($(".form-select option:selected").html()));
  var opcion = $(this).val();
  if(opcion == 1){
    console.log("Se ha seleccionado Género");
  }else if(opcion == 2){
    console.log("Se ha seleccionado Año");
  }else{
    console.log("Opción: "+$.trim($(".form-select option:selected").html()));
  }
});
```

```html
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>
            Prueba
        </title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <filter class="col-3">
               <select aria-label="Default select example" class="form-select">
                      <option selected="" value="0">
                            Filtrar por ...
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            Género
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            Año
                      </option>
              </select>
         </filter>
        <script src="jquery/prueba.js">
        </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okey, he visto y he solucionado ya mi fallo,  tu código funciona perfectamente. Gracias @Kevin Delva